# Java Regex pattern to pull date format up to the first forward slash

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to improve my current regex that matches a date pattern in a url. 
Here is what I have:

`.*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-.*)`

Using a url example such as:

`www.mywebsite.com/2019-10-10-00-00-00/someString/`,

this regex matches as expected `2019-10-10-00-00-00/someString/`

However, what I want is to improve it to just match on `2019-10-10-00-00-00`

I have tried this so far: `.*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[^\\\\/]*)`,

escaping the forward-slash twice as suggested in another SO post (I have also tried single escape). I am no Java expert so I have tested it using a Java-specific regex tester [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html) and it works fine but in code, it is not matching at all.

I am also trying to avoid using something like

`.*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})`

mainly because the date could be `2019-10-10-00-00-00`, `2019-10-10-00-00`, `2019-10-10-00` or whatever, and because there surely has to be a better way.

Any suggestions would be great, or if this is a duplicate of one of the many regex questions out here, I'll gladly close and link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward slash is not a regex metacharacter, and therefore does not require any escaping.  For a one-line solution, use `String#replaceAll`:

```
String url = "www.mywebsite.com/2019-10-10-00-00-00/someString/";
String date = url.replaceAll(".*/(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}-[^/]+).*", "$1");
System.out.println("date: " + date);
```

This prints:

```
date: 2019-10-10-00-00-00
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. However, if all I want to change is the regex and not use replaceAll, what would you suggest. You mentioned that the forward-slash does not need escaping yet my initial attempt of `.*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-.[^/]*)` returned no matches either.

Comment: I can't answer your question without knowing which Java regex API you were using to try to find the matches.  The answer depends on how you are doing it.

Comment: Sorry, I am using java.util.regex.Pattern. I am compiling the patterns like `Pattern.compile(".*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-.[^/]*)")` to find the matching group.

Comment: @johnny_mac I might not use a formal pattern matcher here if your input is just a single logical URL.  But, assuming you did want to do that, [here is a demo](https://rextester.com/VBPU55671) which shows that my pattern does in fact work.

Comment: Hmm, that does show it works here, but not in code, so I'll dig into that and see what I find. Thanks for the input and the answer.

Comment: I found the issue. I was using `matcher.matches()`, not `matcher.find()`